# How to use diesel's filter methods?

Tags: rust, actix-web, rust-diesel

I have a little actix web project. There is a such model:

```
#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize, Insertable, Identifiable, Queryable, PartialEq, Debug)]
#[table_name = "confirmations"]
pub struct Confirmation {
    pub id: Uuid,
    pub email: String,
    pub expires_at: chrono::NaiveDateTime
}
```

Then I have a function where I just wanna get item from the database.
I try to do this:

```
pub fn get_confirmation_item(
    id: &Uuid,
    email: &str,
    pool: &web::Data<PgDBPool>
) -> Result<Confirmation, AppError> {
    let connection = pool.get().unwrap();
    let result = confirmations
        .filter(id.eq(id))
        .filter(email.eq(email))
        .select(id)
        .first(&connection);
    Ok(result)
}
```

And finally I got this error:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `bool: diesel::Expression` is not satisfied
  --> src/apps/users/utils.rs:45:17
   |
45 |         .filter(id.eq(id))
   |                 ^^^^^^^^^ the trait `diesel::Expression` is not implemented for `bool`
   |
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `diesel::query_dsl::filter_dsl::FilterDsl<bool>` for `diesel::query_builder::SelectStatement<schema::confirmations::table>`

error[E0277]: the trait bound `bool: diesel::expression::NonAggregate` is not satisfied
  --> src/apps/users/utils.rs:45:17
   |
45 |         .filter(id.eq(id))
   |                 ^^^^^^^^^ the trait `diesel::expression::NonAggregate` is not implemented for `bool`
   |
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `diesel::query_dsl::filter_dsl::FilterDsl<bool>` for `diesel::query_builder::SelectStatement<schema::confirmations::table>`

error[E0277]: the trait bound `diesel::query_builder::SelectStatement<schema::confirmations::table, diesel::query_builder::select_clause::DefaultSelectClause, diesel::query_builder::distinct_clause::NoDistinctClause, diesel::query_builder::where_clause::WhereClause<bool>>: diesel::query_dsl::filter_dsl::FilterDsl<_>` is not satisfied
  --> src/apps/users/utils.rs:46:10
   |
46 |         .filter(email.eq(email))
   |          ^^^^^^ the trait `diesel::query_dsl::filter_dsl::FilterDsl<_>` is not implemented for `diesel::query_builder::SelectStatement<schema::confirmations::table, diesel::query_builder::select_clause::DefaultSelectClause, diesel::query_builder::distinct_clause::NoDistinctClause, diesel::query_builder::where_clause::WhereClause<bool>>`
   |
   = help: the following implementations were found:
             <diesel::query_builder::SelectStatement<F, S, D, W, O, L, Of, G, LC> as diesel::query_dsl::filter_dsl::FilterDsl<Predicate>>

error: aborting due to 3 previous errors
```

Does anybody know how to fight this error? Dependencies in Cargo.toml:

```toml
[dependencies]
actix-web = "3.1.0"
actix-rt = "1.1.1"
diesel = { version = "1.4.5", features = ["postgres", "uuidv07", "r2d2", "chrono"] }
r2d2 = "0.8.9"
derive_more = "0.99.11"
bson = "1.1.0"
lazy_static = "1.4.0"
serde = { version = "1.0", features = ["derive"] }
serde_json = "1.0.59"
jsonwebtoken = "7.2.0"
envfile = "0.2.1"
env_logger = "0.8.1"
chrono = { version = "0.4.19", features = ["serde"] }
rust-crypto = "0.2.36"
uuid = { version = "0.8.1", features = ["serde", "v4"] }
futures = "0.3.7"
lettre = { git = "https://github.com/lettre/lettre" }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your comparing the `id` as well as the `email` to themselves. What you want is to compare the database field's value to the value in your code.

For diesel, this typically means you need to import your schema, like so:

```rust
use schema::confirmation;

// ..
.filter(confirmation::id.eq(id))
// ..
```

Also take a look at the docs for some exaples: https://diesel.rs/guides/getting-started/

---

Unrelated to this problem, isn't your `id` unique? If so, you could also use the method `find` which allows you to search by primary key.

Oh, and also, you don't need to use `filter` twice. There's a method `.and` which allows you to write a query like so: `schema::id.eq(id).and(schema::email.eq(email))`

Comment: `confirmations::table.filter...` and your variant works. Thank you.